# Is there a way to parse JSON to match a integer to a name in JSON Data

Tags: python, arrays, json

I need help figuring out a solution to my problem. I'm currently trying to make an election system that will parse JSON Data and print out results for the election I input. The problem is that I can figure out how to get python to match an integer (the id of the candidate) to the candidate name so I can count it as their vote.

Also if you could help me on how to make it count the votes that would be very helpful.

**main.py**

```py
import json
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
  db = json.load(f)

  for candidate in db["candidates"]:
    ids = dict()
    idc = candidate["id"]
    name = candidate["name"]
    status = candidate["status"]
    ids[idc] = name
    dids = ids[idc]
    if dids == name:
      print(ids)
  for vote in db["votes"]:
    raw = dict()
    r = vote[0]
    raw[idc] = vote[0]
    print(raw[idc])
    x = 0
    c = Counter(vote[0])
    print ('Candidate {} has {} votes'.format(x, c[x]))
```

data.json

```json
{
  "candidates": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Avia",
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Stan",
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Bob",
    "status": true
  }
  ],
  "votes": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 1, 3],
        [1],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2, 1]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you want to know for each candidate how many times he has voted? for example for candidate with id 1 the answer should be 5?

Comment: why are the votes in multiple lists?

Answer (score 0):

If @Giordano is correct, start with counting the votes per id:

```py
votes_list = sum(db['votes'], [])  # this trick flattens the nested lists
votes_count = {key: votes_list.count(key) for key in set(votes_list)}
```

This gives a dict with the total votes per id:

```py
{1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 5}
```

Then map the results to the candidates:

```py
candidates = db["candidates"]
for candidate in candidates:
    candidate["votes"] = votes_count.get(candidate["id"], 0)
```

This gives the votes per candidate:

```py
>>> candidates
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Avia', 'status': True, 'votes': 5},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'Stan', 'status': True, 'votes': 4},
 {'id': 3, 'name': 'Bob', 'status': True, 'votes': 5}]
```

Finally, sort the candidates by number of votes in descending order:

```py
sorted(candidates, key=lambda k: -k['votes'])
```

Answer (score 0):

What I get from your question is you just need to display which candidate got how many votes. If I interpreted it correct then here is one of the approaches:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict
import numpy as np

db = {
  "candidates": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Avia",
    "status": 'true'
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Stan",
    "status": 'true'
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Bob",
    "status": 'true'
  }
  ],
  "votes": [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [2, 1, 3],
        [1],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 1],
        [3, 2, 1]
    ]
}
count_data = defaultdict(int)
for vote in db["votes"]:
    for data in vote:
        count_data[data] += 1
for data in db['candidates']:
    print ('Candidate '+data['name']+' has got '+str(count_data[data['id']])+' votes')
```

Output:

```
Candidate Avia has got 5 votes
Candidate Stan has got 4 votes
Candidate Bob has got 5 votes
```

Pls Note: Here I haven't read data from a file as you have done, you can update this code accordingly to read data from a file, but the core logic remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

The Joost's answer is correct.

I'd like just to propose another answer with a temporary structure. 
(Explanation is in the comments)

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    db = json.load(f)

# prepare a temporary structure with all the candidates info + initialize number of votes
candidates_dict = {}
for candidate in db["candidates"]:
    candidates_dict[candidate["id"]] = {"name": candidate["name"], "num_votes": 0}

# loop on votes lists and count votes for all candidates
for votes in d["votes"]:
    for candidate_id in votes:
        candidates_dict[candidate_id]["num_votes"] += 1

# just print how many votes each candidate has done
for candidate_id, candidate_info in candidates_dict.iteritems():
    print "candidate {} has {} votes".format(candidate_info["name"], candidate_info["num_votes"])
```

Output:

```
candidate Avia has 5 votes
candidate Stan has 4 votes
candidate Bob has 5 votes
```